# proving definite integral value by induction

Tags: definite-integrals, induction

I  have been trying to prove the following by induction but all my efforts have failed.  the original problem is to prove that

$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^kdx = \frac{2^{2k+1}(k!)^{2}}{(2k+1)!}$

Where $k$ is a positive integer.

after expanding the function using the binomial theorem and taking the definite integral I got this

$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^{2})^kdx  = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac {\binom{k}{i}2(-1)^{k-i}}{2 (k-i)+1}$

Now i need to show that
$ \frac{2^{2k+1}(k!)^{2}}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac {\binom{k}{i}2(-1)^{k-i}}{2 (k-i)+1}$

I took the base case $k=1$ and it works for $1$

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should that be $$\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{\binom{k}{i}2(-1)^{k-i}}{2(k-i)+1},$$ perhaps? It doesn't really make sense as written.

Comment: Oh!  Yes that's  what it means sorry for that misconception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to suppose the thesis valid for $n-1$ and then calculate
$$\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx$$
and integrate by parts using the inductive hypotesis.